# Nested Object Form with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Im trying to implement a way how to enter recipes correctly, so far I have the following:

#### Recipe.cs

```
public class Recipe
{
    [Key]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public int Serving { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients
}
```

#### Ingredient.cs

```
public class Ingredient
{
    [Key]
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}
```

In my Form, I want to Add the Ingredients Inline, with JavaScript Rendering a new pair of fields if needed.

> (The ViewModel is nothing else than a class holding an instance of Recipe)

#### Create.cshtml

```
 @model Vineyard.WebUI.Areas.Admin.Models.RecipeViewModel
 <div class="span9">
    <h2>Create a new Recipe</h2>
    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Create", "Recipes", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <fieldset>
            @Html.LabelFor(r => r.Recipe.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Recipe.Name)
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            @Html.LabelFor(r => r.Recipe.Subtitle)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Recipe.Subtitle)
        </fieldset>
        <div id="ingredients">
            @Html.EditorFor(r => r.Recipe.Ingredients, "Ingredient")
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="addIngredient" class="btn btn-info">Add Ingredient</a>
        <fieldset>
            @Html.LabelFor(r => r.Recipe.Serving)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Recipe.Serving)
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            @Html.LabelFor(r => r.Recipe.Instructions)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(r => r.Recipe.Instructions)
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Save Recipe" />
    }
  </div>
```

#### Shared/EditorTemplates/Ingredient.cshtml

```
@model Vineyard.Core.Entities.Ingredient

<div class="ingredient form-inline">
  @Html.LabelFor(r => r.Amount)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Amount)
  @Html.LabelFor(r => r.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Name)
</div>
```

In the rendered HTML tough, I see the following:

`<input id="Recipe_Ingredients_Amount" name="Recipe.Ingredients.Amount" type="text"  value="">`

Which leads my to believe, that it does not Add the Ingredient as a Member of the Collection, but as a full blown Object by itself. Shouldnt it have an index referencing to it? (Based of this http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

When I look at the Model, that is being passed back to the controller, the Ingredients Part is `null`

So, Im wondering - what am I missing here or doing wrong, that can be changed to actually populate the Collection correctly? From there, I can handle it in the controller to be saved in the right format.

Comment: *Which leads my to believe* - Have to tried it?  It's best to see what happens before assuming something does or doesn't work and posting a hypothetical question about something that may not be a problem.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. As said above, the Model passes back null for the Ingredients. Thats what actually leads me to this. - "Which leads me to believe" - I might be wrong, but its not rendering the Ingredient as Part of the Collection but as a single object.

Comment: Change `public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients` to `public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }` (lose the `virtual` and change `ICollection` to `IEnumerable`).  Also, in your controller, pre-populate the list of ingredients with a single item (for testing) otherwise nothing will appear in your HTML.

Comment: Did this - Actually changed it to IList - Worked like magic, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
```

(lose the virtual and change `ICollection` to `IEnumerable`).

Also, in your controller, pre-populate the list of ingredients with a single item (for testing) otherwise nothing will appear in your HTML.

*This answer was converted from my comment*